# MS Access, Create Query with Fields Selected based on Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a MS Access Database and have stored a table with all available column names (>100 columns).  I added a field to this table which is simply a yes/no or true/false.

I want to build a query in VB or it doesn't have to be VB that the Select fields are based off of what the user selects from this table.  I think adding a combo box or List box to a user form would be too busy as there are more than 100 columns to choose from. I think it is easier for them to open up the table and select that way and then click a button on the form which invokes the build query and Selects only those fields from which the user selected in the Column_Names table.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out; at least this works for my needs.
I added a list box to a User Form which defaults the population off of a query that returns only the fields that have a value of Yes from my Column_Name table.

I then found a function that will I can call that Selects all of the values in this list box.

Then I run this small code to generate the SQL accordingly

```
 Dim ctlList As Control, varItem As Variant
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strSQL2 As String
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim qdfDemo As QueryDef
  Call SelectAll(Form_Custom_Criteria!List27)
  Const conQUERY_NAME As String = "qry_custom_fields"
  ' Return Control object variable pointing to list box.
  Set ctlList = Forms!Custom_Criteria!List27
  ' Enumerate through selected items.
      For Each varItem In ctlList.ItemsSelected
      strSQL = strSQL & ctlList.ItemData(varItem) & ", "
       If strSQL = "" Then Exit Sub
         Next varItem
  CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete conQUERY_NAME
  On Error GoTo Err_cmdTest_Click
  strSQL_2 = "Select " & Left$(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 2) & " FROM Table1;"
  Set qdfDemo = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(conQUERY_NAME, strSQL_2)

 Exit_cmdTest_Click:
  Exit Sub

  Err_cmdTest_Click:
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error in cmdTest_Click()"
  Resume Exit_cmdTest_Click
 End Sub
```